# Weak reference not getting garbage collected?

Tags: java, reference, out-of-memory, weak

I was studying about Weak references. And I understood that all weak references WILL be garbage collected before OutOfMemoryError occurs. I had a simple test something like this (I know catching OOME is not good but just a test) :

```
Integer weakInt = new Integer(10);
WeakReference<Integer> weakReference = new WeakReference<Integer>(weakInt);

try {
    while (weakReference != null) {
        String[] generateOutOfMemoryStr = new String[999999999];
    }
}
catch (OutOfMemoryError oome) {
   System.out.println(weakReference.get());
}
```

I expected null to be printed because the weak reference SHOULD have been collected but I always get an output of 10.

Please let me know where I am going wrong. May be I understood the concept of weak references wrong?

Answer (score 10):

`weakReference` itself won't become null... how could it? However, its *target* can become null.

I suspect you mean:

```
while (weakReference.get() != null) {
```

Moreover, I suspect that unless you set `weakInt` itself to null, that local variable will prevent the `Integer` object from being garbage collected.

*Moreover*, I suspect you'll find your loop *still* won't end - because you're quite possibly asking for more memory than can be allocated even if the `Integer` *is* garbage collected.

Here's a program which demonstrates it working, at least on my box:

```
import java.lang.ref.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer weakInt = new Integer(10);
        WeakReference<Integer> weakReference = new WeakReference<Integer>(weakInt);

        weakInt = null;
        while (weakReference.get() != null) {
            System.out.println("Looping...");
            String[] generateOutOfMemoryStr = new String[999999];
        }
        System.out.println("Weak reference collected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this one..Just a stupid question may be :) After you make weakInt to null, I thought weakReference.get() should always return null?...But surprisingly it executes couple of times before running into OutOfMemoryError..

Comment: @Basith: Why would it always return null? We've just set the value of a *variable* to null. We could set it to refer to a different `Integer` - that wouldn't change the target of `weakReference`. Leaving `WeakReference` out of the equation for the moment, suppose we had `Integer x = new Integer(10); Integer y = x; x = new Integer(20); System.out.println(y);` - what would you expect that to print?

Comment: good that the example was not `Integer wakInt = 10` that would funnier.

Comment: @bestsss: Yes, I thought that myself. I'd personally normally stick with an `Object` example rather than go into the realms of integers and strings, where you could get large behavioural changes with seemingly small source code changes (such as changing 127 to 128 :)